# What is the optimal way remove duplicate property objects from the array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The array of the objects like ages have 5 records, on the basis of sno we want the first element.

```
var ages=[
{name: "Jan", age: "90", sno: "1"},
{name: "Harry", age: "100", sno: "1"},
{name: "Tan", age: "10", sno: "2"},
{name: "Ron", age: "15", sno: "2"},
{name: "Roh", age: "19", sno: "2"},
]
```

Output:

```
[
{name: "Jan", age: "90", sno: "1"},
{name: "Tan", age: "10", sno: "2"},
]
```

I tried to solve this by using ES6 Javascript expression, By getting the duplicate sno, the  looping through the distinc sno and getting the first elements. But I need a better way.

Is there to implement this without using any inbuilt functions?

Comment: Why not try to solve this first?

Comment: You are missing commata.

Comment: Use lodash: `result = _.map(_.groupBy(ages, 'sno'), 0)`

Comment: Please consider adding code examples of possible solutions you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). On each iteration check if `sno` exists in Set. If it is, return `false` (remove the item), if it's not add to Set, and return the reference to the Set (will be cast to `true').

```js
var ages = [{"name":"Jan","age":"90","sno":"1"},{"name":"Harry","age":"100","sno":"1"},{"name":"Tan","age":"10","sno":"2"},{"name":"Ron","age":"15","sno":"2"},{"name":"Roh","age":"19","sno":"2"}]

var result = ages.filter(function({ sno }) {
  return this.has(sno) ? false : this.add(sno)
}, new Set())

console.log(result)
```

You can do the same thing, using a for loop, with a helper object:

```js
var ages = [{"name":"Jan","age":"90","sno":"1"},{"name":"Harry","age":"100","sno":"1"},{"name":"Tan","age":"10","sno":"2"},{"name":"Ron","age":"15","sno":"2"},{"name":"Roh","age":"19","sno":"2"}]

var result = []
var helper = {}
var key

for(var i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) {
  item = ages[i]
  if(!helper[item.sno]) {
    helper[item.sno] = true
    result.push(item)
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: i know, i have sometime used `this` of the array methods, but now, i think, `this` should be reserved for objects with `this` binding.

Comment: It's a bit of an abuse of the binding callback in the method, but it's preferable to a closure because of readability.

Comment: Hi Ori. Thanks for the Answer. Can we acheive this optimally without using any inbuilt javascript function?

Comment: @Adam - see added solution.

Comment: Thanks for the best solution !

Comment: Still trying to get the logic in the `for`.

Comment: If the helper object doesn't have the current `sno` key, add the key to the helper, and push it to result. Only the 1st item will be added to results. The others will be skipped.

Comment: I want to taste that deeply for the future.

Comment: But you mean value instead of key, no?

Comment: I want to check the existence of the key. I set the value to `true` to help me with the check, but I could just as easily have set the value to `undefined`, and checked using the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as closure and filter only unknown `sno`.

```js
var ages = [{ name: "Jan", age: "90", sno: "1" }, { name: "Harry", age: "100", sno: "1" }, { name: "Tan", age: "10", sno: "2" }, { name: "Ron", age: "15", sno: "2" }, { name: "Roh", age: "19", sno: "2" }],
    filtered = ages.filter((s => ({ sno }) => !s.has(sno) && s.add(sno))(new Set));
    
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

By reduce (not very performant, though, due to `some` lookup):

```js
const ages =[
    {name: "Jan", age: "90", sno: "1"},
    {name: "Harry", age: "100", sno: "1"},
    {name: "Tan", age: "10", sno: "2"},
    {name: "Ron", age: "15", sno: "2"},
    {name: "Roh", age: "19", sno: "2"},
];

const result = ages.reduce((acc, x) => {
 if (acc.some(e => e.sno == x.sno) == false)
  acc.push(x);

 return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party.

```js
var mem;
var result = [];
var ages=[
{name: "Jan", age: "90", sno: "1"}
, {name: "Harry", age: "100", sno: "1"}
, {name: "Tan", age: "10", sno: "2"}
, {name: "Ron", age: "15", sno: "2"}
, {name: "Roh", age: "19", sno: "2"}
];

mem = ages[0];
result.push(ages[0]);

for (var i=0; i<ages.length; i++) {
    
    if (mem.sno == ages[i].sno) {
        continue;
    } else {
        mem = ages[i];
        result.push(ages[i]);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```